# Produce this list [0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90] using list comprehension syntax

Tags: python, list-comprehension, sequence

I can produce the list `[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]` using the following code:

```
x = []
y = 0
for i in range(2,21,2):
    x.append(y)
    y += i
```

However I'm not sure how to convert this into list comprehension syntax of the form

[expression for value in iterable if condition ]

Comment: Depending on what else you're doing, can also take a look at `np.cumsum` and `pd.Series.cumsum`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign to `y` inside the comprehension, using an [assignment expession](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/), i.e. using `:=`:

```
y = 0
x = [y := y + i for i in range(0,20,2)]
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that these are doubles of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and then you don't need `y` (but multiplication):

```
x = [i * (i + 1) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use short [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) approach:

```
from itertools import accumulate

x = list(accumulate(range(0,20,2)))
```

---

```
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the relation between indices and numbers:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
 0  2  6 12 20
```

We see this is pretty simple math.

```
>>> [i * i + i for i in range(10)]
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20]
```

Comment: Not to be confused for `[i * i + 1 for i in range(10)]` as I initially did.

Comment: @JonSG also don't confuse `i` and `1`.  YES: `i * i + i`, YES: `i * (i + 1)`, **NO**: `i * i + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Trying to stay as close as possible to the original:

```
x = [
    append
    for y in [0]
    for i in range(2,21,2)
    for append in [y]
    for y in [y + i]
]
```

The original for comparison:

```
x = []
y = 0
for i in range(2,21,2):
    x.append(y)
    y += i
```

Comment: That first block of code makes my brain explode

Comment: I checked the bytecode of the first code block and found that Python is very clever in identifying the innermost double loop as assignments and completely eliminating the overhead of the for loop.

Comment: @MechanicPig Yes, that idiom was [optimized in 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to write the same code using the list comprehension:

- Check if the variable `y` is defined
- If not we assign it using `:=` operator
- Adjust the range's start and stop

```py
x = [y := 0 + i if 'y' not in locals() else y + i for i in range(0, 19, 2)]
```

#### Update:

Using `locals()` and `globals` is not a good practice. Another solution that is simple, and similar to the original for loop is to use the `sum()` function over the range:

```py
x = [sum(range(2, i, 2)) for i in range(2, 21, 2)]
```

Comment: I'd stay clear of `globals()`